# Still & non-resizable secondary tiles

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to show only items on the back of a secondary tile whilst preventing it from animating?

Also is it possible to prevent the secondary size from being resizable? I only want the normal size to be used.

```
private void MenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/Lines and Stations/Emirates Air Line/Greenwich_Peninsula.xaml", UriKind.Relative), new StandardTileData()
    {
        BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/image.png", UriKind.Absolute),
        BackContent = "Caledonian Road & Barnsbury",
        BackTitle = "Exits Expert London",
    });
}
```

Comment: I know you can leave the back content empty, but don't think you can have the front content be empty. You definitely can't prevent resize.

Comment: Is it possible to have BackContent text on the front?

Comment: No, but you could render some Xaml (with text) to an image and set your front backroundimage to the rendered Xaml

Comment: OK cook thanks but you are really supposed to submit your comment as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could create a tile with 'blank' front content, but the OS will still display the front tile and occasionally flip to the back. It won't only show the back content because the front is 'blank' which seems to be what you're going for.

You could render some XAML (with Text) to an image and set your front tile's backgroundimage properties to that image. Allowing you to put any amount of text on the front of your tile. Here's a link to a blog post covering this topic: http://mbmccormick.com/2013/12/creating-dynamic-live-tiles-on-windows-phone/

Also you can not prevent the user from re-sizing the tiles.